# heroku production database not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, cleardb

I have been trying to deploy my local app in production

my **Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'pry', '0.9.12'
gem 'mysql', '2.9.1'
gem 'rails-api', '0.1.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'awesome_print', '1.1.0'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'raddocs', '0.2.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.0'
  gem 'rspec-core', '2.13.1'
  gem 'rspec_api_documentation', '1.0.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'railroady', '1.1.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '1.5.6'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.0'
  gem "factory_girl", "4.0"
end
```

I have the next route in my routes file:

```
post '/region/:id/service' => 'region#service'
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
class RegionController < ApplicationController
  def service
    region = Region.find params[:id]
    render text: region.name
  end
end
```

Ok the problem is that, when I call the service with `curl` in development works perfectly:

```
$ curl -X POST localhost:port/region/6/service -d ""
```

but when I upload the files to heroku, and I call the service again
I'm getting *404 not found (error)* or *500 internal server (error)*

I'm using `cleardb` addon according to [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb).

I think the problem is the DATABASE. At first I wrote my **database.yml** for *production* enviroment the database info according to the following:

```
$ heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
```

but I think is not neccesary because heroku can do it automatically according to this line... I think so

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
```

I tried in the both ways without results and I really don't know why the service is crashing when I try to do a query in production.

my **database.yml** looks like

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  password: xxx
  database: myapp.development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: mysql
  password: xxx
  database: myapp.test_1
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: xxx
  username: yyy
  password: zzz
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: us-cdbr-east-04.cleardb.com
```

Comment: please post your logs so that we can see your error and debug from there.

Comment: Just a guess, but I think you will have to remove the default postgres database addon.

Answer (score 1):

after some debugs I found that the ids in heroku are assigned each 10 numbers for example one of my tables region looks:

```
+----+-----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name      | state | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | Brasil    |     1 | 2014-01-08 13:12:56 | 2014-01-08 13:12:56 |
| 11 | Chile     |     1 | 2014-01-08 13:12:56 | 2014-01-08 13:12:56 |
| 21 | Peru      |     1 | 2014-01-08 13:12:56 | 2014-01-08 13:12:56 |
| 31 | Argentina |     1 | 2014-01-08 13:12:56 | 2014-01-08 13:12:56 |
+----+-----------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

"ClearDB uses circular replication to provide master-master MySQL support. As such, certain things such as auto_increment keys (or sequences) must be configured in order for one master not to use the same key as the other, in all cases. We do this by configuring MySQL to skip certain keys, and by enforcing MySQL to use a specific offset for each key used. The reason why we use a value of 10 instead of 2 is for future development."

thanks.